# How do memory-clean apps work?

Tags: operating-systems, memory, memory-usage

In terms of operating system architecture, what does a memory-clean software to get rid of all data that fill the virtual memory? I assume that it simply saves all RAM data into a file, but how does it exactly do this? What happens if you delete a file while a process that has resources on that file is executing?

Hope this is not a too-broad question.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat, sharing your knowledge helps everyone. Tell us what is wrong with this question and why it didn't meet your needs and why deserves a downvote. I know this is Q&A site and there is full of stupid, lazy, and no-previous-research-and-senseless questions that piss you off, but I truly think there is no reason to be so narrowed minded with the general rules and to punish with downvote. Even though this have been already asked, I did previous research and I didn't find any convincing answer, so ended up here, to find out if people can help me out. Good luck with that.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They [*don't* work.](http://www.howtogeek.com/171424/why-memory-optimizers-and-ram-boosters-are-worse-than-useless/) Basically they're [snake oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil) whose only function is to extract money from the gullible.

Comment: I'm not sure whether OP is asking about 3rd-party snake oil programs, or about *swapping*, which is an OS feature.

Comment: Ahá! That was my suspicion...

Comment: @amon so, all programs that cleans memory are snake oil? Could be this achieved without 3rd party software? Are they just forcing a task that is cyclically executed by the OS?

Comment: @Manu SuperUser might be of a bit more help there - [Using a Windows Memory Cleaner/Optimization application](http://superuser.com/questions/615358/using-a-windows-memory-cleaner-optimization-application) and [How does the 'memory clean' app work](http://superuser.com/questions/663876/how-does-the-memory-clean-app-work)

Comment: @MichaelT wow, that's effectiveness. Thank you very much.